# systemd timer running rsync at 3am and stopping at 6am

Tags: backup, systemd-timer

How to make a `systemd` `.timer` , that starts `rsync A U@H:B` at 3am and stops (e.g. `kill -TERM`) at 6am on weekdays ?

Do I have to make one that starts at 3am,
and second that runs `kill` at 6am
and for both two files (i.e. `.service`, `.timer`)?
Or is there another way?

Comment: Hi, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278564/4671, if you feel like attempting an answer.