# cant get a cronjob run at startup on ubuntu 16.04, any way around?

Tags: cron, startup

I put command `@reboot /home/user/script.sh` in `sudo crontab -e` but it won't run, `@reboot sleep 60 && sh /home/user/script.sh` won't run either. already `chmod 777` and `-x` it. im using hiveos(based on ubuntu 16.04) is there any other way to autorun script at reboot? I'm not sure what desktop environment is being used but it's not gnome so the usual .desktop at `/.config/autostart` cant be used. adding a line to `/etc/rc.local` also doesnt work. please help me out

Comment: Not sure if this helps your case, but one alternative to cron can be systemd and its timers. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278564/cron-vs-systemd-timers

Comment: What is your script attempting to do? Does your cron log indicate the script sin _not_ running? Does the cron daemon mail any error messages etc. from the script to the root user? Note that if the script is trying to open windows etc., that there is no guarantee at all that a graphical user interface is up and running at reboot, and even if it were, the cron job would not intrinsically know about it.

Comment: You have a lots of duplicates here.

Comment: my script is simply `#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/chia-blockchain
. ./activate
chia start all && chia stop timelord-only
sleep 666 && /home/user/TTDPoolClientLinux`